# How secure needs an user activation to be?

Tags: authentication, registration, user-registration

When a user registers on my app he gets an email. In this email is a link to activate/confirm his account.

My idea was: The database record has a field `activated (boolean)`, a field `activation code (objectid/guid)` and `id (objectid/guid)`.
So the email would contain a link to

```
https://my.foo.bar.com/auth/activation/{userid}/{activationcode}
```

which would activate the account.

The actual question is: Is this secure (enough) ? I'm fairly new to authentication in general and I am not sure if this way is the correct way. Should I just use 2 activation codes instead of userid/activation code?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when User you try to register in app or any website Confirmation or activation Code will be sent to the User by the Particular website or app So you just need a activation Code and User Id is enough , For the high security you can use encryption and decryption for send and receiving confidential information(For Ex: User Id,activation Code ) between you and user

Answer (score 0):

> Is this secure (enough) ?

The answer is "yes" for the most use cases, if my imaginable "most use cases" approximately matches yours. Only you can know if this is secure enough for your case.

In fact this is a procedure to confirm that a given email address belongs to a person - is it what you actually need?

If your GUID is good enough (e.g. 128 bits cryptographically secure random) it is as safe as email delivery channel. Email delivery channel will be secure enough for "most use cases", but might not be sufficient for some areas, e.g. financial stuff.